# PHP-EWS (GarethP) setReplyTo

Tags: php, php-ews

Using PHP-EWS ([GarethP](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews)), I am attempting to `setReplyTo` like this:

```
use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword("host", "username", "password");
$message = new Type\MessageType();
$message->setSubject("Some Subject");
$message->setBody("Test Email");
$message->setToRecipients("test@test.com");
$message->setReplyTo("me@there.com"); // <-- this is the 'ReplyTo' address I want to set.
$api->sendMail($message);
```

But this does not have any affect, and the recipient is then replying to the sender/from address.

The Api callback shows:

```
'replyTo' => NULL,
```

Any ideas on how solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out.
For anyone else experiencing a similar issue, here is what I found.

Within the `MessageType.php` file, the `addReplyTo` and `setReplyTo` functions are missing.

Adding these in the same way as the `setToRecipients`, `setCcRecipients` and `setBccRecipients` functions solves the problem:

```
public function addReplyTo($recipient)
    {
        return parent::addReplyTo(ensureIsMailbox($recipient));
    }
public function setReplyTo($recipients)
    {
        $this->replyTo = [ ];
        $recipients = ensureIsArray($recipients);

        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
            $this->addReplyTo($recipient);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```